# What is the fundamental difference between passing arguments to a function v/s using class level variables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Am new to Typescript and Angular-2 world with prior experience of Java and Angular-1.5.

Assume there is a component class where few variables (say coming as JSON response or few generated after performing some Math/Calculation on JSON), are to be used across functions.

1. Is it good to refer to those variables as class level members i.e.,

   ```
   processFunction(){
       ....
       ....
       this.someVar = this.someService.getData();
       ....
       ....
       this.functionA(); //funcA needs this.someVar
       this.functionB(); //funcB needs this.someVar
   }
   ```
2. Save variables as function scope members and pass them as arguments i.e.,

   ```
   processFunction(){
       ....
       ....
       let someVar = this.someService.getData();
       ....
       ....
       this.functionA(someVar);
       this.functionB(someVar);
   }
   ```

What is  the best approach to follow ?

PS : Above code is an abstraction of wider usecase where there will be many variables to be scoped as function variables (let) n pass them as Function arguments.

Coming from Java background, best practice in Java would anyday be have class level variables if there are more than 2 Functions sharing variables.

Need suggestion on Typescript front.

Comment: If this value is only to be used within `processFunction`, and not to exist for the entire lifetime of the instance, it should be a local variable. (In all languages, including Java). Will you need the property after `processFunction` has returned? What would you initialise it with in your constructor?

Comment: @Bergi Answer is yes and no, may or may not need property after processFunction has returned. Want to know what to do in both cases.

Comment: Well the answer is *yes use an instance property* and *no use a local variable* then.

Comment: can `this.functionA` be called outside of `processFunction()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or principle of least knowledge is a design
>   guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented
>   programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose
>   coupling. The guideline was proposed by Ian Holland at Northeastern
>   University towards the end of 1987, and can be succinctly summarized
>   in each of the following ways:[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)
>
> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only    units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only   talk to its friends; don't talk to    strangers.
> - Only talk to your  immediate friends.